# Choosing the right Sharepoint path in Power Query

Tags: sharepoint, powerquery

When loading data from Power Query the path varies according to how the user logs in (virtually, locally, etc.).

I am unable to pass the correct path to Power Query. I first select the most recent user and then their path (there might be more than two different paths), so far I have:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Content("C:/Users"),
    #"sort_user_table" = Table.Sort(Source, {{"Date accessed", Order.Descending}}),
    User = Table.Range(#"sort_user_table",1,1)[Name]{0},

    user_path = if Folder.Files("C:\Users\"& User & "path1" <> null
    then
    Folder.Files("C:/Users"& User & "path2"
    else null,

    #Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(user_path,{{"Name", Order.Descending}}),
    Keep60files = Table.FirstN(#Sorted Rows",60),
    Custom1 = Binary.Combine(Keep60files[Content]),
    #Import CSV" = Csv.Document(Custom1, [Delimiter=",", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]) 
.
.
.

in
#"Sorted Rows1"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How is this related to SharePoint? Provide a few sample values from `Source`. Where is `path1` and `path2` coming from? Perhaps share a little more on what you are trying to do in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table.Buffer() is a work around to getting try ... otherwise to work for Folder.Files()

```
let  
username="temp",
Source = 
try Table.Buffer(Folder.Files("C:\"&username&"3")) otherwise 
try Folder.Files("C:\"&username&"13") otherwise 
try Folder.Files("C:\"&username&"2") otherwise 
#table({"Content","Name","Extension","Date accessed","Date modified","Date created","Attributes","Folder Path"},{})  //blanktable
in Source
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It is really helpful. However, I run into the problem described in the link and that is what is causing me trouble. 

I need a way to TRY two or three different paths  I have tried:

try Folder.Files ("C:\Users\"& Username & "path1" otherwise Folder.Files ("C:\Users\"& Username & "path2".

with no luck :-(

Comment: Sorry I was on holidays. 
It works!   But only if I leave the first Table. Buffer in the try statement and the following try statements without it!

Thanks so much

Comment: Thanks. I will edit answer to reflect that